# Can an Australia visa rejection blackmark me forever?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration

I have a parent living in Australia, last time I visited them with a tourist visa and everything went alright. The second time I applied for a family sponsor visit visa by mistake and had it refused since for having this sort of visa your sponsor must be an Australian permanent resident, and my parent is a temporary resident. I didn't get the visa, didn't visit the country. I could have payed a little more to try on a different visa type but I decided on not doing that and traveling elsewhere.

Could this black mark my immigration record forever, for Australia or any other country? My record are clean and I never over stayed or broke any immigration law, they did not put "visa rejected" stamp in my passport.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure exactly that you mean by "blackmark." It won't result in an automatic ban in most countries (if even in any), but it probably will result in greater scrutiny since you will have to answer "yes" when asked if you've ever been rejected for a visa. You can explain that you applied for the wrong type of visa, which most reasonable people might accept if you explain it plausibly.